# Is there any Delphi XE2 styles gallery?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, firemonkey, vcl-styles

In XE2 there is a new function : 'styles', for VCL(*.vsf) and Firemonkey (*.styles), and some are provided in *C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Redist\styles* directory.

As it seems to be easy to create a new style, is there any 'styles Gallery' Web site or blog somewhere ?

Comment: I uploaded a collection of Vcl Styles in this location http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/wiki/VclStylesCollection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, for the moment there is no such thing like a gallery of styles for FireMonkey or VCL styles. But if you want to create you own try these entries in my blog which show an easy way to create/modify new VCL styles and FireMoney styles in few clicks. Both articles include additional styles to download.

- [Exploring Delphi XE2 – Tweaking the FireMonkey Styles](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/tweaking-the-firemonkey-styles/)
- [Exploring Delphi XE2 – VCL Styles](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/exploring-delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-part-i/)

Comment: Yes your blog is my reference about styles, but I thought that may be someone else (Embarcadero ??) would have share his work.

Comment: +1 because I can't give more. I haven't seen any official online presentation except this one. I don't get why Embarcadero when developed something like Firemonkey don't have some official showroom (except the few examples).